# ionic2 - add modal as static function

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have this `static openModalInfo()` function in my `app.component.ts`:

```
import { Platform, ModalController } from 'ionic-angular';
export class MyApp {
static modalCtrl:ModalController;
constructor(platform: Platform, 
              statusBar: StatusBar, 
              splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }
static openModalInfo() {
    let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(ModalInfo);
    modal.present();
  }

}
```

The idea is to have all the `modal` at the `MyApp` so that I can call it when error happen:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import {MyApp} from '../../../app/app.component';//<-- add MyApp.

export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

onModal(){
  MyApp.openModalInfo();//<-- call this function.
}

}
```

However I have got this error:

> Error in ./HomePage class HomePage - inline template:34:6 caused by:
>   Cannot read property 'create' of undefined

Which, I believe, `create` is refer to `this.modalCtrl.create(ModalInfo)` in `MyApp`.

How can I resolve this?

Or how else can I create a universal modal function so that I can call from any component?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you have some sort of `Utility` Provider class which you can inject into any of the components

```
@Injectable()
export class Utility{

  constructor(private modalCtrl: ModalController){}

  openModalInfo() {
     let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(ModalInfo);
     modal.present();
  }
```